# Swift: Dynamic Framework Localization

Tags: swift, localization, frameworks

I create a Dynamic Framework Project,
and create Localizable.strings for localization

but when i use this framework on other app project.
the framework localization can not work

is Localizable.strings duplicate? how can i do